# Swift Breakpoint Debugging Extremely slow on Xcode 13.4.1

Tags: swift, xcode, performance, debugging, breakpoints

Recently I updated my Xcode to 13.4.1 version, when I was debugging swift files, the breakpoint was hit but lldb was loading all the time which was resolving local variables.

[image]

Is anyone who has the same question?

Comment: I also have this issue, it sometimes takes up to a minute to resolve a the variables. Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Since when I upgrade my Xcode to 14.0, it seems swift debugger become faster than that in 13.4.1. You should make a try. @Rem-D

Comment: It seemed quicker initially after an upgrade. Thanks for the advice! But now (on 14.2) it's back to taking minutes resolving variables again. Not sure if @Mesird or anyone else has this issue on 14.2?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?